# Sourcing R files housed within an R project and maintaining relative paths

Tags: r, rscript

Okay, so I like to use R projects in Rstudio for scripts and data that I'm working with. However, let's say I want to source those scripts in another directory...R does not detect the .Rproj file unless the script is called from the directory where it is housed. Is there any way to source an R script that is part of an R project from another directory?

This is relevant as I have a system where I perform analyses and make figures in one directory, but then produce LaTeX documents that use those figures in another directory. I like to be able to source the R scripts that make the figures and save them to the directory where I'm writing in LaTeX.

Here's a MRE:

With an R project already created in directory (done via Rstudio)...let's call it ~/test.

Create some data:

```
a <- 1:10
dat <- data.frame(a = a, b = a + rnorm(length(a), 10, 2))
save(dat, file = "test.RData")
```

Place the following script in ~/test. Let's call it test.R.

```
load("test.RData")

pdf(file = "plot.pdf")
plot(b ~ a, data = dat)
dev.off()
```

Works great, right? But if we try the following from any other directory R can't figure it out.

```
cd ~
Rscript ~/test/test.R
```

Any thoughtful solutions? I suppose it's easy enough to just `setwd()` in the script that I'm sourcing the original script from, but this sort of defeats the whole purpose of using R projects.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `Rscript` has nothing to do with RStudio or RStudio projects. If you call a script from a specific directory, unless otherwise specified that directory will be the root directory where it looks for files (since you don't give absolute paths). In your case you call `Rscript` from your home directory, so that this is where R is looking for `"test.RData"`.

Comment: Sorry, should have made this clearer in the question. Yes, I call the script from the home directory, but the script is found in ~/test and the data is loaded from within the script. Perhaps I'm just confused on what an R project is and how it should be used

Comment: Yes I understand what you did, and as I explain in my first comment the behaviour is as expected. An RStudio project has nothing to do with R itself. If you set up an RStudio project, it will (amongst other things) create a metafile with RStudio-specific parameters. As you already point out, you need to use `setwd` to specify the *working directory* if you're calling R (or `Rscript`) from a different directory.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `setwd("~/test/")` at the beginning of the script and if necessary change it back later on.

Comment: Yes I had included this in the bottom of the original question.